# Loop runs for the first 3 iterations but gives error after the 3rd

Tags: loops

I have a loop that I am trying to run for 6 different part numbers - for each part number, it creates some graphs, calculates Cpk values, and creates a summary table of Cpk values for different parameters of the part nubmer.
The loop runs just fine for the first 3 part numbers but not for the others. I tried running it starting with the 4th part number and got the same error. Then tried running it starting from part number 5 and again, same error. The error message is as shown below. I can't find anything in my code or the data that would make the data for the 4th and later part numbers to act differently than first 3 part numbers.

Error in dimnames(x) <- dn :
length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent
Calls:  ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> qcc -> rownames<-

Comment: Please explain more, add some code snippets.

Comment: I am new to this and might be missing something very basic - including not knowing where in the code the issue is. So I am copying the entire code below. All I know is it runs well for the first 3 part numbers (sku[1], sku[2]. sku[3] but doesn't for the rest. I don't see anything different in the data or the code that would cause sku[4] to be any different than sku[1] to sku[3].

Comment: Hi @Hamid, Sorry I could not get any clue from your explanation, But i can suggest:- try to debug the array at the index it gives the error. if the value is ok there, then pass the value to your graph function and check if any error happens with that. Your index starts with 1, the index of an array should start with zero. ( i did not get it ). also please mention the programming language name. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.